# DataGrid XAML control can't be scrolled by touch

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm developing a uwp app. The app has a DataGrid XAML control.

My problem is that I can scroll it by mouse, but I can't scroll it by touch. Curiously, I can scroll it by two fingers touch.

Please let me know how to fix the problem.

Here is my code.

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Loaded="ContentGrid_Loaded">
        <SplitView x:Name="spritView"
                   IsPaneOpen="{Binding ElementName=HamburgerButton,Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   DisplayMode= "CompactInline"
                   PaneBackground="LightGray"
                   PanePlacement="Left"
                   CompactPaneLength ="0"
                   OpenPaneLength="200"
                       Margin="0,48,0,0"
                       >
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Button x:Name="BtExit" Click="BtExit_Click">
                                <Image Source="/pictuer/left_arrow.png" Height="32"/>
                            </Button>
                            <TextBlock Text="Category" Width="140" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockFontSize1}"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                          >
                <StackPanel Background="Snow" >
                    <controls: x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                           GridLinesVisibility="All" AlternatingRowBackground="LightCyan"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding DefuctLists}">
                        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding Item_Lb}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>

                    </controls:DataGrid>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource borderLineLightGray}" Margin="0,8,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>

        </SplitView>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DataGrid XAML control can't be scrolled by touch

For checking your code, I have a little confused, why you insert `DataGrid` into `ScrollViewer`, and why you set the `DataGrid` parent panel as `StackPanel` that will make the actual height of `DataGrid` larger not the content's height, and it will make `DataGrid` could not be scrolled.

If we remove `ScrollViewer` and replace `StackPanel` with `Grid`, and the `DataGrid` will response touch scroll.

```
<SplitView.Content>
    <Grid>
        <controls:DataGrid
            x:Name="dataGrid"
            AlternatingRowBackground="LightCyan"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            GridLinesVisibility="All"
            >
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn
                    Binding="{Binding}"
                    Header="Category"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    />
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</SplitView.Content>
```

Comment: Hi Nico. Thank you for your solution.

As you told me, I removed ScrollViewer and replaced StackPanel with Grid, the DataGrid finally responsed touch scroll. 

The problem has been completely solved.


Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, it's not implement yet, you cannot scroll on Xbox and other touch devices. See the GitHub issue:
https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2864